# Jquery: Is there something wrong with my .load()?

Tags: jquery, image, select, load, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with this code...
The preloader shows up when this function is fired, but it never hides. 
The page also shows up before the image inside it is finished loading.

Is there something wrong with my load function?

```
$('select.select').change(function() {

    var x = $(this).val();

    //Hide the current page and show the preloader
    $('#page' + x).hide();
    $('#pageLoader *').show();

    //when current page is loaded, hide preloader and show page
    $('#page' + x + ' img').load(function() {
      $('#page' + x).show();
      $('#pageLoader *').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: My drop down is just a simple drop down. Where the value of each option increases by one until a certain number. There shouldn't be an issue with it since I am using it for another part of code that is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If the `<img>` element is being created after the event handler is set you will need to bind the handler using *live()* instead, which will bind to existing and future elements matching the selector on the page:

```
$('#page' + x + ' img').live("load", function() {
  $('#page' + x).show();
  $('#pageLoader *').hide();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

If the `<img>` *already* has a `src` attribute you need to loop through and check in the case it comes from cache, like this:

```
$('#page' + x + ' img').one('load', function() {
  $('#page' + x).show();
  $('#pageLoader *').hide();
}).each(function() { 
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: @cat - another issue is the browser may not be loading it if it's hidden...which browser are you in?

Comment: Im using the safari browser on the ipad. 

I used a .load function like the one i posted in my question in my $(window).load function and it works perfectly, But that only works on the first image when you first load the page.

Now im trying to make it work for my other images on my page but that function doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I am also checking it on firefox on the computer, but more so on the ipad safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a url as the first parameter of the `load()` function.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: There are 2 load methods, he wants the image's `load` event handler :)